# What should I do when the question to which I answered has changed completely?

Tags: discussion

A question was asked.  I answered that question in a full and concise way, and received a number of up votes, but it was not marked as correct.

Some time later, the question changes in such a way that my answer looks quite bizarre and unrelated, and the down votes come flooding in.  My net score on that question is now very much in the negative, despite the original answer being very well received.

What should I do?  Simply delete my answer?  Is my score affected?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I don't know how the question was changed because you didn't link us to it.

If it was totally changed and turned into a new question, I think you should:

- *keep* your answer
- rollback the last edit
- ask OP to post a new question instead of editing the current one

If the edit (any edit) deviates from the original intent of the post, then it's a bad edit and shouldn't be made/approved, no drastic changes are allowed to be done on a post - if that's the case then it's a sign that the post should be a *new* one and *not* an edit.

Comment: And if the OP reverts the edit, consider flagging it. Questions really should not be "recycled".