# Is it OK to edit your own question so radically that it breaks all existing answers?

Tags: discussion

Sometimes I come across a situation in which I provide an answer to some clueless question from some confused fella, explaining what's happening, and sure enough shortly afterwards the question is edited so radically that neither my answer nor answers of others make any sense anymore.

My question is simple: shouldn't there be a limit to how much a question can be edited before the author is required to either delete it or ask a new one?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions

Comment: [What should I do when the question to which I answered has changed completely?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/315387/1842065)